# How to find all Endpoints of route (Apache Camel, Java)

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have several routes and many endpoints in Camel context. So need to get all endpoints created by one Route:

```
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    RouteBuilder route1 = new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file:data/inbox?noop=true")
                    .routeId("myRoute1")
                    .enrich("http://website.com/file.txt")
                    .to("file:data/outbox")
                    .to("mock:someway");
        }
    };

    RouteBuilder route2 = new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("file:data/outbox?noop=true")
                    .routeId("myRoute2")
                    .to("mock:myMom");
        }
    };

    context.addRoutes(route1);
    context.addRoutes(route2);

    context.start();

    // TODO 

    context.stop();
```

And before stop I need get all endpoints which created by myRoute1  ??? for example:

1.file://data/outbox
2.mock://someway
3.http://website.com/file.txt
4.file://data/inbox?noop=true

I can get only all Endpoints of Camel context as: context.getEndpoints()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

1. Give your route an routeId to be able to identify it later.
2. Get the RouteDefinition from the Route from the CamelContext and filter the List of Outputs for the ToDefinition objects.

   ```
    List<ProcessorDefinition> outputProcessorDefs = exchange.getContext().getRouteDefinition("[routeId]").getOutputs();
    // Iterate and get all ProcessorDefinition objects which inherit from the ToDefinition
   ```

Comment: Yeah that would work too, but then you need to be aware that there are other EIPs that also take endpoints, like toD, recipient list, wire tap, etc.

Comment: Sure you are right. But with this "solution" you'll get only the definition of the route and not the concrete dynamic endpoints. So you could react too if you'll find a definition for recipientlist or any other dynamic endpoint. But to be honest I do not even know why he needs the endpoints of one route at all :-)

Comment: You may need for example to check if in the adviced route, the endpoint you replaced is there.

Answer (score 5):

An endpoint is not associated to a single route, as it can be reused among multiple routes. So you cannot really find out from the endpoint itself. But what you can do is to store all the endpoints in a local list, before you add the route, and then afterwards get all the endpoints again, and then *diff* these 2 lists of endpoints. all the new endpoints was then added by the new route.

Comment: WOW! CLAUS! Thank for you answer! I thought about it. Your books are awesome! Thank you!

Comment: @user2959384 a good way to say "thank you" on this site is to upvote/accept answer(s).

Comment: It's also possible to get all the endpoints from CamelContext:

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/CamelContext.html#getEndpoints()